# Removing elements of one list with respect to another list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `A` and `B`. I am removing element from `A` which is less than `tol`. But I also want to remove element from `B` corresponding to the removed element from `A`. For example, `[[2.22105075e-18]]` was removed from `A`. Corresponding to this, `[[4,13]]` should be removed from `B`. I present the current and expected output.

```
import numpy as np
A= [[9.16435586e-05], [0.000184193464], [9.28353239e-05], [2.22105075e-18]]
B= [[13, 14], [4, 5], [5, 14], [4, 13]]
tol=1e-12

CA=[[x[0]] for x in A if x[0]>tol]
CB=[x for x,y in enumerate(CA) if list(y) in B]
print(CB)
```

The current output is

```
[]
```

The expected output is

```
[[13, 14], [4, 5], [5, 14]]
```

Comment: Why do you import NumPy when you only have and want lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could process the two in parallel with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
CA, CB = map(list, zip(*((a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B) if a[0]>tol)))

# or
# CA, CB = map(list, zip(*(x for x in zip(A, B) if x[0][0]>tol)))
```

Output:

```
# CA
[[9.16435586e-05], [0.000184193464], [9.28353239e-05]]

# CB
[[13, 14], [4, 5], [5, 14]]
```

Comment: What if ```A=[]```, ```B=[]```? In this case, I want ```CA, CB=[]``` but I get the error: ```ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)```.

Comment: Then the best would be to have an external check `if A: … else: CA, CB = [], []`

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you. Is it possible to update the answer based on if ```A, B=[]```?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea to achive your stated goal is as follows:

1. Pair up both lists `A` and `B` with `zip` to give pairs of the form `(a, b)`.
2. Keep only the bs for meach `a b` pair which satisfy the predicate on `a`.

We can implement this several ways.

#### Comprehension implementation

```py
A= [[9.16435586e-05], [0.000184193464], [9.28353239e-05], [2.22105075e-18]]                              
B= [[13, 14], [4, 5], [5, 14], [4, 13]]                                                                  
tol=1e-12                                                                                                
                                                                                                         
result = [b for a,b in zip(A, B) if a[0]>tol]
```

#### Explicit loop implementation

```py
result = []                                                                                              
for i in range(len(A)):                                                                                  
    if A[i][0] > tol:                                                                                    
        result.append(B[i])
```

Both methods essentially implement the outlined algorithm.